# How to put curly braces on new lines when autoformatting Dart with VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

My autoformat gives me this

```dart
code() {
  more code;
}
```

when I prefer

```dart
code()
{
  more code;
}
```

(Probably because I started with Delphi's Pascal :-)).

I tried `File`/`Preferences`/`Settings`, and searching the settings for "brace." Options for placing an open brace on a new line *do* show up, but they are marked as being for JavaScript, TypeScript, CSS, LESS, and SCSS. *I'm looking for Dart/Flutter.*

Comment: You cannot.  The Dart formatter is intentionally opinionated to ensure consistency and to minimize debate.  See [its FAQ](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: for other languages, see the settings with the substring `braceStyle` in their ID.

Comment: @jamesdlin If you turn your comment into a response I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments by jamesdlin, this is not possible. The Dart formatter is intentionally opinionated to ensure consistency and to minimize debate. See [its FAQ](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ).